# Android Intent filter with http/https not working

Tags: android, react-native

I've tried several things I've found in searches and nothing seems to work for http or https urls. I'm using the below code right now in my AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name" android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="example" android:host="item" />
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="example.com" android:pathPrefix="" />
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="example.com" android:pathPrefix="/" />
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="example.com" android:pathPrefix="/somepage" />
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="example.com" android:pathPrefix="/somepage/" />
</intent-filter>
```

example://item does work to launch my app. https://example.com does not work and it just opens the page in the browser. I have tried splitting up each data tag into different intent-filters and it still does not work. Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:
Full manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="***"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" tools:node="remove"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
      android:largeHeap="true">
      <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name" android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="example" android:host="item" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="example.com" android:pathPrefix="" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="example.com" android:pathPrefix="/" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="example.com" android:pathPrefix="/somepage" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="example.com" android:pathPrefix="/somepage/" />
    </intent-filter>


      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>


</manifest>
```

Edit 2:
I've found that the intent works (opens in app) if I run this through command line:
`adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://example.com/" *package*` and the trailing slash is required. It does not work without the trailing slash.
However, clicking a link in the android chrome browser (with or without trailing slash) does not open in the app. The link gets opened in the browser and not in the app.

Comment: please add full manifest please

Comment: @Cliff added above

Answer (score 3):

Adding the following fixed the issue:

`<data android:pathPattern="/.*"></data>`

I hope this will be Helps you

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can test it with this command in your adb

```
adb shell am start
    -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW
    -d "https://example.com" *YOUR PACKAGE*
```

on your second DeepLink remove (android:pathPrefix="")

```
<data android:scheme="https" android:host="example.com" />
```

Make sure that intent filter is inside of Activity tag , like this :

```
  <activity
        android:name=".activities.ParseDeepLinkActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <data
                android:host="deeplink"
                android:scheme="wizzo" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Edit:

Please remove :

```
android:label="@string/app_name" android:autoVerify="true"
```

Comment: I tried with just `<data android:scheme="https" android:host="example.com" />` and no luck. I do have the intent-filter inside the activity tag. I edited the question with the full manifest.

Comment: Through the command line I get this error: `Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=https://example.com/... flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.example launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } }`

Comment: I removed label and autoverify and there was no change, both on chrome browser on the device (Galaxy s6 android 7.0) and through command line. Same error as above through command line.

Comment: adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "wizzo://deeplink" wizzo.mbc.net  --   tested on my project and works prefect

Comment: `example://item` through command line works for me.
`https://example.com/` through command line with the trailing slash also works. Without the trailing slash I get the same error as above.
Through the android chrome browser, neither with nor without trailing slash work when clicking links.